# Unique Identifier for Android Device - Unavailable

Tags: android

I want to use a Unique identifier for my library as multiple app in the same phone can utilise same unique ID. For example Android Phone A - can have 3 apps in the Phone A with same library integrated with all 3 apps, so all 3 must use the same ID to identify this as 1 device, rather than having 3 different IDs. Additionally, this app can be released from 3 different build machines and the app package names might not be known always.

- I have tried using Advertisment ID but it not achievable in all phones, few phones give access where few fail to retrive it.
- IMEI - requires additional permission and not achievable after android 10 as mostly the results achieved are empty string
- I have tried Android ID which is unique but if you have 2 different build machine for different or same apk it will assign 2 different Android ID rather than 1.
- Tried Shared preferance, Broadcast reciver, Content Provider and File R&W approach to create own unique Identifier but all of them fail to achieve.
- As for Broadcast Reciever both app need to be active at the same time to share information
- For Content Provider can only have 1 Content provider with same name and if the particular app created the content provider is deleted than the content provider is also deleted.
- Shared preference need to provide the package name for other application and read mode is not available. It do not work with the library package name, it requires app package name.
- File R&W - Some phone works and some dont, sometimes after deleting the file, it still shows file exist, some manufacture phone do not allow read from public directories.

Devices tested:
Samsung - Android 9, 10 and 11
MI - Android 9, 10 and 11
Huawei- Android 9 and 10

Comment: You want your library to be able to track same device even across multiple applications??

Comment: yes @TaranmeetSingh

Answer (score 4):

As defined by [Android Best Practices](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids) you **should not use any Hardware ID** like IMEI, MAC Address etc.

That leaves you with either Google Ad ID(GUID) or Firebase Installation Id(FID) or you can create your own unique ID solution which are all **software generated ID's** which can be reset by the user by things like factory reset.

If you are fine with the fact that some small sample size of users will still be able to reset the device ID which is expected among current companies then you can use the [Account Manager API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager) to share the ID generated by application. Although this is used to create a single login for all applications of a company by sharing the tokens and user name you can **repurpose the Account Manager API** for sharing the unique ID. Whenever an application is installed write your unique ID to Account Manager and when a new application is installed check if this ID already exists if it does then use the same else create a new one and write to Account Manager.

Still there will be some use-cases where the same phone will be represented by a new ID but such exceptional cases will be fractional and IMHO can be overlooked.

Comment: Thanks for the Account Manager API approach, I am looking into it, but I do not want my end user to be able to see that something is Logedin programatically for my Library under Settings -> Accounts, as its not an app and it can be integrated with multiple other apps within the same device, as a result it do not fit my business model. Is their any other approach you are aware of, which can achive the similar objective but without end user being able to review it? @Taranmeet Singh

Comment: @AHMED yes it is understandable that end user might suspect the unusual login then I believe you have to provide some AIDL interface that can talk to other applications with same library but I believe most app developers might not like the Idea of you there application talking to multiple applications and them not having any control over it also some might use proguard that might strip down that part of your library.

Comment: True, I agree. Currently I have implemented the Account Manager API approach and whenever my inital application is deleted, it also deletes the account created for unique identification. is this default mechanism for Account Manager or I am doing something wrong? @Taranmeet Singh

Comment: @AHMED yes that is default mechanism but you should read the data from account manager only once say at launch application launch then save the same in you application preferences if the user deletes the first application whenever the next application is launched check in account manager if the account is not there recreate using the data you have in shared preferences

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to achieve the Account Manager approach, but when I have tried to install my SDK with multiple apps from one build machine and I am able to achieve my task and retrieve data from the account manager. However, when I try to create the apk from my colleague's build machine (by which I am refering to a different PC) using the same code, as this was something which I had issue while using the Android ID as well ( which gives same Android ID if I created the apk from same build Machine/PC and gives different android ID if the same program was run from a different build machine).

Comment: When I install the apk build from my colleague build machine, it throws an error:

'Error: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10415 cannot explicitly add accounts of type: com.example. '

I feel it can be because of UID.

Comment: Additionally, I have also tried to place the sharedID on my Sdk and application end  but when I try to install from my colleague's PC it thows a different exception after adding it on application side. 
Added code:  android:sharedUserId="com.example"

Error: The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE

Can you suggest, if their is a way to retrieve the account info when the app is build with different PC.  @Taranmeet Singh

Comment: Hi @TaranmeetSingh, thanks for the answer! However, I've got an issue implementing the approach can you please look into it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71120775/android-account-manager-not-detecting-package-type

Comment: @PreetPatel you need same debug  certificate to sign applications checkout my comment on your question